# Javascript private variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make my `tabs` variable private and only accessible from within the `return {}`... `console.log(tabs)` returns `undefined`...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Site.page = (function () {
        return {
            init: function () {
                Site.page.tabs.init();
            },
            //manage deal tabs
            tabs: (function () {
                var tabs = null;
                return {
                    init: function () {
                        console.log(tabs);
                    },
                    show: function (tab) {
                        $('#deal-tabs > div.selected').removeClass('selected');
                        $(tab).addClass('selected');
                    }
                }
            })()
        }
    }());

    Site.page.init();
});
```

Comment: It prints out `null` for me, as it should.

Comment: It looks like your code does what you want it to do. Are you trying it in some browser I've never heard of?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you name both the function and the variable the same name? If you only need the variable in return{} then declare it in that block of code, not outside.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Declaring it inside the `return {}` is the same as declaring it outside of it within the nearest enclosing function.